# samsung galaxy nexus charging problems

Tags: charging, samsung-nexus-s

it doesn't charge until battery totally dies and few minutes after that only, charging triggers.

Not sure if it an issue with charger or the phone battery.

Comment: Have you tried using a different charger? Or charging through the PC's USB? Or maybe a different battery? [Just to rule out some of the issues]

Comment: doesnt work using PC's USB...I dont have extra battery...most likely an issue with the cable...I will check